# How can I pass data from one view to another in android?

Tags: java, android

I have two views named: `first_view` and `second_view`.

The first view consists of a button and an editable text view. The second view consists of a single text view.

In my first view, I want to put a number in the datable text view. As I click the button, it should display the number in the second view.

How can I code Java classes for the two views?

Comment: any code yo tried? paste will modify it

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to setText within the same Activity, if not so then tell me, Ill change my answer.

Here is what you have to do.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {  
Button btn;
EditText et;
TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbtnID);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEtID);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtvID);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String myText = et.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(myText); 
    }
});
}
}
```

If you want to pass text between two Activities then use `Intent`.

In your current `Activity` do this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
String str = yourEditText.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("edittextvalue" , str);
startActivity(i);
```

Then  in next Activity do this..

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String myEtText;

if (extras != null) {
myEtText = extras.getString("edittextvalue");
yourTextView.setText(myEtText);
}
```

Comment: Dear i have tow views and there will two activity. Now how can pass data from one activity to another activity.

Comment: how  to pass data from one activity to another activity by using intents

Comment: Thanks for your great effort regarding your post

Comment: @ishaq ahmad, please check the right mark which you see on the left of the starting of my post to accept it as your answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

if  Two Views in the same Activity , you can do that

```
    Button btn;
    EditText txtInput;
    TextView txtShow;
    //btn=firstView.findViewWithTag(tag)
    btn=firstView.findViewById(R.id.**);
    txtInput=firstView.findViewById(R.id.**);
    txtShow=secondView.findViewById(R.id.**);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input=txtInput.getText().toString();
            txtShow.setText(input);
        }

    });
```

if you have Two  Activity :

```
Button btn;
EditText txtInput;
String VALUE_KEY="show";
private void test()
{


    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.**);
    txtInput=(Button)findViewById(R.id.**);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input=txtInput.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.Class);
            intent.putExtra(VALUE_KEY, input);
        }

    });

}
```

On the AnotherActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent=this.getIntent();
        String value=intent.getStringExtra(VALUE_KEY);

        TextView view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        view.setText(value);
    }
```

Comment: two view means that there are two xml file named first_view and second_view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
put your value in String: `String et_str = EditText.getText().toString();`

When you call the other intent,

```
Intent i = new Intent(first_view .class, second_view.class);
i.putExtra("REF",et_str);
StartActivity(i);
```

In The Second View, get this value using `getExtra()`